# Run a Github action only within one organisation

Tags: azure-pipelines, github-actions

I have a Github repo which, for historical reasons, is mirrored at another org. The repo has an Azure pipeline to run tests and do the copy to the mirror, which I'm looking to migrate to Github Actions.

Is there a way to ensure that the GHA only runs at the source repo?

Here is a snippet of current Azure pipeline yaml, showing the code that does the mirroring:

```
variables:
- group: GH

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- bash: |
    export CLOUDYR_REPO=$(echo $(Build.Repository.Name) | sed "s/Azure/cloudyr/")
    git push --prune https://$(ghPat)@github.com/$CLOUDYR_REPO +refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
  displayName: 'Copy to Cloudyr'
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')

- bash: |
    # other checks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's fairly basic: just add an `if` clause to the `job`.

```
on: [push, pull_request]

name: myjobname

jobs:
  myjobname:
    if: github.repository_owner == 'Azure'
    # rest of workflow will run only if the org is 'Azure'
```